test=model.predict([text]) entire project runs six times consecutively
It seems that when the line test=model.predict([text]) is executed, your entire project runs six times consecutively, and when you close the opened windows, it makes predictions.
You can see the code snippets below.
[main file]
print("test1")
def classification():
    print("test2")
    raw_text = str(entry.get("1.0", tk.END))
    tahmin_sonucu = main(raw_text)
    categories_label.config(text="Kategoriler: " + tahmin_sonucu)

[main function]
from simpletransformers.classification import ClassificationModel

labels = ["Bilim Kurgu", "Ekonomi", "İslam", "Polisiye", "Romantik", "Sağlık", "Spor"]
model = ClassificationModel('bert', 'bert_model', num_labels=7, use_cuda=False,
                                    args={'reprocess_input_data': True, 'overwrite_output_dir': True, 'num_train_epochs': 3,
                                        "train_batch_size": 16, "fp16": False, "output_dir": "bert_model"})
print("test11")
def main(metin):
    tahmin = None
    print("tes12")
    tahmin=model.predict([metin])

    print(labels[tahmin[0][0]])
    
    return labels[tahmin[0][0]]


Outbut

You never showed the part of the code where you call test=model.predict([text]) or any of the functions that you defined in your example code.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
